# Overlap and non-functioning filling in groupplots

Tags: pgfplots, groupplots, fillbetween, dateplot

I'm trying to place multiple plots in the same figure. In each plot I'd like to have a certain region highlighted. However, there is significant overlap between the plots and the highlighting doesn't work at all. Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\usepgfplotslibrary{
  dateplot,
  fillbetween,
  groupplots
}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,
      use comma}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{groupplot}[
    date coordinates in = x,
    xticklabel={\year},
    no marks,
    scaled y ticks = false,
    xtick = {1990-01-01, 1995-01-01, 2000-01-01, 2005-01-01,
      2010-01-01, 2015-01-01},
    group style = {group size = 2 by 1,
         horizontal sep =1cm,
         vertical sep = 1cm,
      %   xlabels at=edge bottom
       },
    ]
    \nextgroupplot
    \addplot[blue] coordinates {
      (1995-01-01,0.00419152827774827)
      (1995-11-28,-0.0034102121140176)
      (2002-08-22, 0.0076423873165794)
    };
    \addplot[orange] coordinates {
      (1995-01-01, 0.00082432847433811)
      (1995-11-28, -0.00109642468521187)
      (2002-08-22,0.0184758085974366)
    };
    \path[name path=T](rel axis cs:0,1)--(rel axis cs:1,1); % obere Achse
    \path[name path=B](rel axis cs:0,0)--(rel axis cs:1,0); % untere Achse
    \addplot[green, opacity=0.5] % Fülleigenschaften
      fill between [%
      of=T and B,% zwischen oberer und unterer Achse
      soft clip={domain=1995-01-01:2000-01-01}% Einschränkung des Zeitraumes
    ];
    \nextgroupplot
    \addplot[blue] coordinates {
      (1995-01-01, 0.0120056542276519)
      (1995-11-28, 0.00138251635145359)
      (2002-08-22, 0.00493968691707103)
    };
    \addplot[orange] coordinates {
      (1995-01-01, 0.00012103619804904)
      (1995-11-28, 0.00397950876242348)
      (2002-08-22, 0.0141901119999108)
    };
    \path[name path=T](rel axis cs:0,1)--(rel axis cs:1,1); % obere Achse
    \path[name path=B](rel axis cs:0,0)--(rel axis cs:1,0); % untere Achse
    \addplot[green, opacity=0.5] % Fülleigenschaften
      fill between [%
      of=T and B,% zwischen oberer und unterer Achse
      soft clip={domain=1995-01-01:2000-01-01}% Einschränkung des Zeitraumes
    ];
  \end{groupplot};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result this gives is [image: Problematic output]

Comment: is [this](https://www.overleaf.com/3197016ykwbkd#/8948348/) the result you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding

```
set layers,cell picture=true
```

to the `groupplot` options fixes it. This appears to be a workaround for a bug that is current as of pgfplots 1.12.